LSTM forecasting predicts zeros
i'm building an LSTM model to forecast future total number of cases for covid 19 using OWID dataset
i use a multivariate series of 6 columns including the date column,
the Problem is i get all zero predictions however this not the case when i use univariate series using only single column the total_cases column
here is the code i use
url = "https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)

# Filter the data for a specific location, e.g., 'United States'
location = 'United States'
df_location = df[df['location'] == location]

# Select relevant columns and set the date column as the index
selected_columns = ['date', 'new_cases', 'new_deaths', 'total_cases', 'total_deaths', 'reproduction_rate']
df_location = df_location[selected_columns]
df_location['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_location['date'])
df_location.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# Handle missing values by filling them with the mean of the column
df_location.fillna(df_location.mean(), inplace=True)

# Function to create a multivariate dataset for LSTM
def create_multivariate_dataset(data, time_step=1):
    X, Y = [], []
    for i in range(len(data) - time_step - 1):
        X.append(data[i:(i + time_step)])
        Y.append(data[i + time_step, 0])  # Predicting 'new_cases'
    return np.array(X), np.array(Y)

# Convert the data to numpy array and scale it
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(df_location)

# Create the dataset with a specified time step, e.g., 60 days
time_step = 60
X, y = create_multivariate_dataset(scaled_data, time_step)

# Reshape the input to be [samples, time steps, features] for LSTM
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], X.shape[2])

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Define the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(time_step, X.shape[2])))  # Adjusted input_shape
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))  

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=1)

# Make predictions on the test set
test_predict = model.predict(X_test)

# Inverse transform the predictions to get actual values
test_predict_full = np.concatenate((test_predict, np.zeros((test_predict.shape[0], scaled_data.shape[1] - 1))), axis=1)
test_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predict_full)[:,0]

output of test predict is always all zeros
what i'm doing wrong

You are using relu as the activation function for the output layer, which outputs values in the range [0, ∞). The following line of the code provided by you:
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

indicates that the desired output range is between 0 and 1. To achieve this, you should use the sigmoid activation function instead, which will ensure that the output values are within the range (0, 1).
Here's how you can modify the output layer:
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

The sigmoid function outputs values in the range (0, 1), which aligns with your requirement.
